# openssh-client - what is correct location for global known_hosts file?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I'm a bit confused what the "correct" path for ssh's systemwide known_hosts file is..

the `man ssh` says `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`
whereas [SSH Host Key - What, Why, How](https://www.ssh.com/academy/ssh/host-key) talks about `/etc/ssh/known_hosts`.

Are both locations valid? Is the difference a historic artefact? Is it distribution specific? Which file path should be used?

Comment: as a general advise, usually _your_ `man` page has the most accurate information, because it's tied to _your_ distribution and your software version. Manuals from the internet, even if it's the official developer website, may contain features not yet available in the version you're actually running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For [OpenSSH](https://www.openssh.com/), its man page is the canonical documentation. According to [ssh(1) - OpenBSD manual pages](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh), `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` is the official path for the “systemwide list of known host keys”. This applies to all releases of OpenSSH and is not specific to any one distribution – or OS for that matter.

[SSH.COM](https://www.ssh.com/) is the website for SSH Communications Security, a commercial company set up by the original designer of the SSH protocol and writer of the first implementation. It has no direct relationship with the [OpenSSH project](https://www.openssh.com/) which is maintained by a group of [OpenBSD](https://www.openbsd.org/) developers based on a fork of an early release of the original SSH program.

I don’t know where SSH Communications Security got `/etc/ssh/known_hosts` from (presumably their own or the original implementation) but as a third-party source of information, it is not relevant to users of OpenSSH. Out of interest, I checked the [earliest version (rev 1.1) of the OpenSSH man page](https://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/ssh/ssh.1?rev=1.1&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup) and it had historically been using yet another (slightly different) path, `/etc/ssh_known_hosts`.